# How to configure jsdom to preserve tag name case?

Tags: jsdom

Look at these lines:

```
var doc = jsdom.jsdom("<moshe></moshe>");
console.log(doc.childNodes[0].tagName);
```

The second line writes "MOSHE" to the console in uppercase that means jsdom recognized my string as HTML and not XML. How can I enforce jsdom to preserve tag name original case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you need parse XML, why dont you use XML parsers instead?

Comment: I don't use other XML parsers b/c I need to adopt the nodes created by the parser by my main HTML document created by jsdom and append these nodes into the main HTML hierarchy. Using another XML parser creates XML nodes incompatible with jsdom. On the other hand I want to preserve the case in order to be able to execute case-sensitive xpath expressions on these nodes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTML standard [tagName](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-tagname) is supposed to be uppercase in a HTML document.

> The tagName attribute must run these steps:
>
> 1. If context object's namespace prefix is not null, let qualified name be its namespace prefix, followed by a ":" (U+003A), followed by its local name. Otherwise, let qualified name be its local name.
> 2. If the context object is in the HTML namespace and its node document
>      is an HTML document, let qualified name be converted to ASCII
>      uppercase.
> 3. Return qualified name.

Jsdom currently does not support XML documents (officially), since there's no differentiation internally between a HTML and XML document.

To parse as XML in v1.0+ you have to provide htmlparser2 as the parser, jsdom then implies parsing as XML based on a `<?xml` directive. This might become unnecessary if [#883](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/pull/883) gets merged, in which case a `parsingMode` option will be introduced, which accepts "xml" and switches to a xml parser.

Ultimately, work is underway to go about this problem, however an immediate solution to parsing XML with jsdom is not in sight.